# How to Fetch and Display an Image from an express backend server to a React Native frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

Searching this same topic i`ve found another question:
[How to Fetch and Display an Image from an express backend server to a React js frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829529/how-to-fetch-and-display-an-image-from-an-express-backend-server-to-a-react-js-f)
and in the comments has this:"Convert your blob to File var file = new File( res.data, { type: "image/jpeg" } ); var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file); Then use this imageUrl ". So I've done it similar to his code and got error.

```
fetchImages = () => {
 const imageName = 'Vinicius_0-1577392361334.jpg';
 api.get(`/image/${imageName}`)
  .then(res => {
    var file = new File(res.data, { type: 'image/jpg' });
    var imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    return (
      <Image source={imageURL} />
    )
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)        
  });}
```

```
routes.get('/image/:file', (req,res) =>{
  let file = req.params.file;
  let fileLocation = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'backend/uploads/', file);

  res.sendFile(`${fileLocation}`);
});
```

```
         .....
<View style={styles.viewBotao}>
     {this.fetchImages()}
         .....
```

[Console OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2cAo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign you `imageURL` to state variable

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        imageURL: ''
    }
}

fetchImages = () => {
    ...
        var imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        this.setState({ imageURL });
    ...
}


<View style={styles.viewBotao}>
     <Image source={this.state.imageURL} />
</View>
```

Comment: thanks ! but this throw that error `TypeError: parts.map is not a function
at Function.createFromPart`. Making more research i ve seen that the problem maybe a **blob** response that i cant convert into a file.

Comment: Yep, I just show you the way to deal with `imageURL`. you could try to use https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob to download your file instead.

Comment: In my case , i think doesnt make sense download the file, because the client will have a list of services, and each services will have a image relatated. If the client open every service , will download all images in server.