# Display Image in Reactjs from Express backend

Tags: reactjs, express, frontend

This is the data I am receiving from backend. I want to display the **image** on frontend using **Reactjs**. Simply doing it like this does not work.
`<figure><img src={image} alt="" /></figure>`.
I don't know how to do this.

```
address: "Anarkali Bazar London"  
availableDate: "2021-07-07T00:00:00.000Z"  
companyName: "realme"  
description: "hello"  
image: "image_1626778257560.jpg"  
isAvailable: true  
pricePerDay: 8  
productTitle: "product"  
state: "London"  
userId: "60f65fe9af2bc10004fc29ec"  
__v: 0  
_id: "60f6aa925ded840004691150"
```

Comment: You don't have a reference to the image. You only know it's name. Make your backend either send a path to the file (be it on the disk or online like a CDN), or make a function in your frontend that can resolve an image name to a full image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should take a look at this [How to Fetch and Display an Image from an express backend server to a React js frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829529/how-to-fetch-and-display-an-image-from-an-express-backend-server-to-a-react-js-f) it solves your problem.
somethings to note

1. Make sure you sent the image as a blob i.e when React was sending the image to the express server, ensure you converted it to an image/blob format. This will ensure that you are indeed getting a blob/file/image format back.
2. Ideally, and this is a suggestion after you must have solved the above problem. Consider uploading the image to an image hosting service like Cloudinary, and saving only the links in the database, thereby allowing your initial approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to specify the path to you image.

```
<figure><img src={`path/to/image/${image}`} alt="" /></figure>
```